# Where is Users Identity Verification info is stored?

Tags: apex, soql

The [View Your Users’ Identity Verification Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_passwordless_login_check_verified_users.htm?search_text=TwoFactorMethodsInfo) article describes how we can view information about each user’s identity, yet it is not clear where this data is kept? In what object? I can create a list view with all those fields (User Verified Email, Temporary Code, U2F Security Key etc.) but how can I access them in apex (or soql) for example?

EDIT - Added screenshots

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Seems quite likely related to **[`VerificationHistory`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_verificationhistory.htm)**. I would guess the "fields" just indicate whether or not a record exists with the given `Activity` specified. Notice the values for that picklist:

> The action the user attempted that requires identity verification. The label is User Activity. Available values are:
>
> - AccessReports—The user attempted to access reports or dashboards.
> - Apex—The user attempted to access a Salesforce resource with a verification Apex method.
> - ChangeEmail—The user attempted to change an email address.
> - ConnectToopher—The user attempted to connect Salesforce Authenticator.
> - ConnectTotp—The user attempted to connect a one-time password generator.
> - ConnectU2F—The user attempted to register a U2F security key.
> - ConnectedApp—The user attempted to access a connected app.
> - EnableLL—The user attempted to enroll in Lightning Login.
> - ExportPrintReports—The user attempted to export or print reports or dashboards.
> - ExtraVerification—Reserved for future use.
> - ListView—The user attempted to access a list view.
> - Login—The user attempted to log in.
> - Registration—Reserved for future use.
> - TempCode—The user attempted to generate a temporary verification code.

The **Usage** section also recommends how to query, for example:

> ```
> SELECT
>     Activity, EventGroup, Policy, Remarks, Status,
>     UserId, VerificationMethod, VerificationTime
> FROM VerificationHistory WHERE LoginHistoryId = '0YaD000#########'
> ```

You might want to swap out the `WHERE` clause to instead filter on `UserId`.

Comment: It seems that VerificationHistory doesn't contain that info. At least for community users it doesn't. I attached screenshots to my question showing that VerificationHistory doesn't have records for a community user who verified their email.

Comment: @Eduard Did you try any other value? Did you try with a standard user?

Comment: Yes, when I ran the query without the "WHERE" clause records only  for standard users were returned. What I am interested in is how I can see Identity info for community users.

Answer (score 2):

This info and the verification status is being kept in the TwoFactorMethodsInfo sObject. You need to grant "Manage Two-Factor Methods through API" / "Manage Two-Factor Methods through the UI" permission first to see this object.

The difference between TwoFactorMethodsInfo and VerificationHistory is that the former stores information on the channels available for 2FA and whether these have been confirmed. The latter stores transaction data about 2FA verifications done and their respective results.